# how to check disabled status of input field react-test-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using @testing-library/react for react unit test.

I wanna do unit test of input field's disabled status and value.

Below is dom element from chrome inspect.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text..." aria-disabled="false" class="styles__TextInput-sc-1vdcacp-2 grIDkE" value="test">
```

I tried like below, but it does not work.

```
expect(screen.getByText('Enter text...')).toBeVisible();
expect(screen.getByRole('input')).toBeVisible();
```

Please let me know how to test input field and it's disabled status and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getByRole, but parameter should be `textbox`, not `input`.

And for input field's value, you can test it like this:

```
expect(screen.getByRole('textbox').value).toBe('test');
```

For check disabled status, you can use `toHaveAttribute` like this:

```
expect(screen.getByRole('textbox')).toHaveAttribute(
      'aria-disabled',
      'true'
    );
```